# C++ Random numbers 0 - 16

Tags: c++, random

Im working on a hangman game for class, i'm having trouble getting a random number.
Everytime I run the code I get the same number. Not sure what the problem is here, anything would help.

```
string pickWord(){
    int random = rand() % 17;
    string word = ::wordList[random];
    cout << word << endl;
    return word;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to seed random with time, otherwise it will always be the same.

take a look at this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/

your code should look like this

```
string pickWord(){
    srand (time(NULL));
    int random = rand() % 17;
    string word = ::wordList[random];
    cout << word << endl;
    return word;
}
```

and also you have to add an include

```
#include <time.h>
```

This way, random will be dependant on the time, it is run, not on the compilation time.